# When use jshint for a hello world script, I got "line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'script'."

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jshint

This is my simple *hello world* programme.

```js
function sayHello() {
    return 'Hello world';
}
```

And my `jshint` configuration:

```js
{
  "browser": true,
  "browserify": true,
  "devel": true,
  "script": {
    "lint": "jshint src"
  }
}
```

and `package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "myangular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

When I run `jshint`, get the following error:

> `$./node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint src`
>
> `src/hello.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'script'.`
>
> `1 error`

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. I put *script* in a wrong place.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer perfectly.